# Django redirect behavior with back button

Tags: django, redirect, back-button

I'm running into an issue now where I have a "random" link on my site to see a random user. The way I have it set up is to get the user_id and then use redirect to serve the proper page. The issue I'm running into is if I click the random button multiple times, clicking on back will bring me back to the page before the "random" clicks.

To be more concrete, this is what's happening:
HomePage, Click Random (go to /user1/), Click Random (go to /user4/), Hit back (end up on HomePage). In this scenario I'd like to end up on /user1/

This is the random view method:

```
def Random(request):
    user = helpers.GetRandomUser()
    return redirect('user_display', user_slug=user.username)
```

The template just has a link to /random/ which gets routed to the above view.

Edit: Apparently it works as expected in Firefox but in Chrome. I'd like it to have the Firefox-like behavior everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly you click two times on a link to the same url (like `/random_user/`) and you respond with a random redirect. This seems quite unconventional and it doesn't sound so wrong that Chrome might view this as a single history entry.

To archieve your wanted behaviour across browsers simply generate the random url before you render your random user link.

As you want to use it in multiple views, [write a custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag
def random_user_url():
    user_url = # generate your random user url
    return user_url
```

In your template:

```
{% load your_tag_lib %}
<a href="{% random_user_url %}">Random user</a>
```

This way every click leads the browser to a different url and will be memorized as seperate history entry.

Comment: We thought of doing it this way but felt that it would have a negative impact on SEO so we have it passed to a view which then redirects to a user page.

Comment: Something to add is that clicking random will end up redirecting to another url but using a view. So click on /random/ will redirect to /user1/ so /user1/ is what appears in the URL.

Comment: Another issue is tracking - how would I track that the "random" url was clicked?

Comment: I'm no SEO specialist, but I am not sure if this way the SEO impact isn't even worse. Every time the link is followed the spider lands on a different page. You could mark the link with `rel='no-follow'`. Any way, another way that would solve tracking is to generate a link to `/random_link/?user_id=<the_generated_random_id>`. The random_link view then tracks the click and redirects to the user with the given id.

Comment: Yea I ended up just switching to this view and rewriting the view to append a /r/ at the end to indicate the source. It keeps the URL clean but also provides some tracking. So now the random link is to /user1/r/ and the view handles that properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to force the browser not to cache the page. So, clicking back button sends request to server and now you can catch it and redirect him to the desired page.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control

@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)
def func()
  #some code
  return
```

Comment: I tried adding this but it didn't change anything. I'm still seeing the back button go to the original page.

Comment: The request will come to the original page...but you should have something like a request middleware that checks for the user_id and if its not there,you should redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: The above code just instructs browser not to cache the page. so, if you hit back request will come to server and will not be rendered from cache

Comment: I understand but this is the series of pages the user sees in Chrome:
/dan/ -> /user1/ -> /user4/ -> /user5/ -> (back) -> /dan/

In Firefox, it's:
/dan/ -> /user1/ -> /user4/ -> /user5/ -> (back) -> /user4/

Comment: a middleware will look into all requests...wats the problem in it?

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, when you say "Back Button" do you mean:

1. Browser Back Button
2. Your own creation of a Back Button

If 2, are you doing this via client side? Such as via javascript?

Comment: I would save the last site path as a session, then retrieve via the view when the page is called again via the back button.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using sessions for this since it seems like a hack.